# How Can I Get Multiple HwndHost Instances in a Single Canvas to Overlap Properly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, plugins

I have a WPF application that is composed of many different processes.   These processes each provide a window that is effectively a plugin to the main application.  I use the [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in .NET to embed each window into the main application, as a child window, inside the WPF visual tree.  However, there are times that the different windows overlap with each other.  I have one window in particular, that in that case, should be the top-most window, i.e., it should draw on top of its siblings.  However, even when that window has the [WS_EX_TOPMOST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style set, it seems to render beneath the other plugin windows.  How can I enforce a Z-Order concept for cross-process HwndHosts?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you'll need to share some code with us.